# jQuery form validate not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My problem is i want to validate my form inputs trough jquery.validate. this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#formreg').validate({ 
    rules: {
        Username: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        Password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        Password2:{
            required:true,
            minlength:8
        },
        Name:{
            required:true   
        },
        Lastname:{
            required:true
        },
        Address:{
            required:true
        },
        Telephone:{
            required:true
        }
    }
});
return false;
});
```

with the above code the only validation errors that i get back are only for the email,password2 and address, I want to get the validation errors for all the form inputs. Thank you

This is my html form

```
<form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="formreg">    
<input type="text" name="Username" value="" id="Username">
<input type="password" name="Password" value="" id="Password" />
<input type="password" name="Password2" value="" id="Password2"/>  
<input type="text" name="Name" value="" id="Name"/>
<input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" id="Lastname" />
<input type="text" name="Address" value="" id="Address"  />
<input type="text" name="Telephone" value="" id="Telephone"  />    
<button name="Login" type="button"  onclick="submitform();">Register</button>
```

Comment: Why is there a `return false` inside your DOM ready handler?  That makes no sense whatsoever.  Also, you need to show the relevant HTML markup of your form.  How else are we supposed to know why your code is not working?

Comment: I have removed the "return false" and i have posted my html form, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button...

```
<button name="Login" type="button"  onclick="submitform();">Register</button>
```

You do not need any inline JavaScript with jQuery.  And you certainly don't need an `onclick` handler for the jQuery Validate plugin.

Change your `type` into `submit` and remove the inline click handler...

```
<button name="Login" type="submit">Register</button>
```

---

You also cannot put a `return false` into your DOM ready handler...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formreg').validate({
        // your rules
    });

    // return false;  // <- REMOVE THIS LINE

});
```

---

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/M9Y6L/1/**

Comment: I'm using a "button" because i had some problems with the "submit" on my css. The onClick handler calls a different function, not the jQuery validate plugin. It is just for submitting the form...

Comment: @user3537552, It's also likely what's breaking your code.  If you'll examine my code, I also use a `<button>`.  **Changing it into a `type="submit"` should have absolutely no bearing on your CSS**; otherwise, fix your CSS.  [See the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Y6L/1/).  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it worked with the submit button! Thank you so much! Is there a way to style my submit button seperatly from the form?

Comment: @user3537552, not sure what you mean by _"separately"_.  Using CSS, you can style whatever you want.

Comment: I gave a class on my submit button, and i'm trying to style it throught css. but for some reason the submit button gets the form's css...

Comment: @user3537552, still don't have any idea what you're talking about.  You'll have to post a new question specifically about the CSS and show your relevant CSS/HTML.